# How can I parse this Json string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have validated it with http://jsonlint.com/, and it is a valid Json string. However, I cannot parse this with Newtonsoft Json in CSharp. I am using Newtonsoft V9.0.1.

```
[{
    "Test": {
        "ID": "Test1",
        "Name": "Name1"
    }
}, {
    "Test": {
        "ID": "Test2",
        "Name": "Name2"
    }
}]
```

The exception returned is: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0."

Comment: *I cannot parse this with Newtonsoft Json in CSharp*.   What have you tried that did not work?  Can you give a [mcve] for your problem?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot parse this? Could you please provide more details, and maybe also some code?

Comment: The code is here, if you insist JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(".... the string goes here...");

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/0jkDO6

Comment: How are you getting the string and where do you deserialise it? This could be the problem. As others have said show the code.

Comment: dbc, thanks for taking up the effort to try it out. I edited your sample, and I noticed that the json string sent to me was a UTF-8 string with BOM at the front. Seems like Newtonsoft is not able to handle UTF-8 string with BOM.

Comment: Oh, your JSON string probably has a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) hidden at the beginning.  To remove see [json.net deserialization throwing exception when json is loaded from project resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881804) or [Strip Byte Order Mark from string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317700) -- and I see our comments crossed.

Answer (score -1):

First add the Newtonsoft json using Nuget Package Manager

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public List<Test> test { get; set; }
}
class Test
{
    public string ID;
    public string Name;
}
```

You can implement a class that holds the fields you have in your JSON

and then use the generic version of DeserializeObject:

```
List<Wrapper> tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Wrapper>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: That will not work.  The outermost JSON container is an array, not an object.

Comment: Changing the type in the generic to an array or a list is an easy fix for that

Comment: type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Now its working fine i had made some edits.:) :)